# What is the relationship between Kerberos tickets and Kerberos / AFS tokens?

Tags: kerberos

Based on the `man` pages, it seems that `kinit` gets me a ticket, and `klog` gives me a ticket and token. If the token can be gotten using a ticket, then why do I still get prompted for a password for `klog` if I do `kinit` first?

In general, what is the exact relationship between the ticket that `kinit` gives me and the token/ticket that `klog` gives me?

Answer (score 0):

klog is a very old program that should not be used anymore. It was the AFSized version of kinit back when AFS was entirely kerberos 4 based. Most AFS installations use either aklog or afslog to get AFS tokens from krb5 tickets.

AFS tokens are just boring old service tickets, but in addition to being stored in the kerberos tgt file, they are also stored in process space so that the kernel can use them for file access to AFS servers. This is what the aklog program does.

Most sites that use AFS also include a kinit that will run the aklog program after getting the ticket. You can think of klog like that.